# Override Block to render my custom Template

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, overrides

I'm trying to override native block Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php, because i want to render my custom(copied) template addtocart.phtml and use my custom methods on this template.

Here is my DI - Wodev\Guestcheck\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Wodev\Guestcheck\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Here is my block - Wodev\Guestcheck\Block\Product\View.php

```
    <?php

namespace Wodev\Guestcheck\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    private $_helper;

    public function __construct(
        \Wodev\Guestcheck\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context,$urlEncoder,$jsonEncoder,$string,$productHelper,$productTypeConfig,$localeFormat,$customerSession,$productRepository,$priceCurrency,$data);
    }
}
```

Here is my layout - Wodev\Guestcheck\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
            <block class="Wodev\Guestcheck\Block\Product\View" name="custom.addtocart" template="Wodev_Guestcheck::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My template is not rendering. Please,help to find out why?

Answer (score 1):

**You dont need to override core block.**

Simply put this xml format in your `catalog_product_view.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Wodev_Guestcheck::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Wodev_Guestcheck::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I'm going to realize custom methods, which i want to use in template

Comment: and as i know, action methods in layouts are deprecated

Comment: As Alkos said - `<action>` has been deprecated, `<arguments>` should be used where possible - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act

Comment: So, how can i render my template using overriding block??? I want to make some methods on it, which i want to use on custom template